Bialgebra structure on self dual associative algebra
Given a finite-dimensional associative $\mathbb{k}$-algebra $A$, one can define its dual $A^*$ as the $\mathbb{k}$-vector-space $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{k}}(A, \mathbb{k})$ with $A$-multiplication given by $a \cdot \alpha(x) = \alpha(x \cdot a)$ for $a,x \in A$ and $\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{k}}(A, \mathbb{k})$.
Thus it makes sense to ask whether as $A$-modules, $A \cong A^*$. If this is indeed the case, $A$ is called self-dual. Now on $A^*$ there is a canonical coalgebra-structure given by $\Delta = \mu^*$ (where we silently identify $(A \otimes A)^* \cong A^* \otimes A^*$). Given an $A$-isomorphism $\phi: A \to A^*$, one can define a map $A \to A \otimes A$ by $$\tilde{\Delta} :=  \phi^{-1} \otimes \phi^{-1} \circ \mu^* \circ \phi.$$
Is this a comultiplication on $A$ turning it into a bialgebra with the apropiate counit? I have tried writing it down, but it seems that this depends on the choice of $\phi$. If this is the case, when can one expect to have a suitable $\phi$ such that this works?

No, there's no reason to expect this. Let's take arguably the simplest family of examples, $A = k^X$ where $X$ is a finite set. Bialgebra structures on $A$ correspond to monoid structures on $X$. Where is such a thing supposed to come from?
Explicitly, the $k$-linear dual $A^{\ast}$ can naturally be identified with the free vector space $k[X]$ on $X$, where the dual pairing takes an element of $A$, thought of as a function $X \to k$, and evaluates that function on elements of $X$, and the coalgebra structure is given by $\Delta x = x \otimes x$ for $x \in X$. The $A$-module structure is given by pointwise multiplication (that is, if $f(x) \in A$, then $f(x)$ sends $\sum c_x x \in A^{\ast}$ to $\sum c_x f(x) x$) so $A$ is self-dual, and every $A$-isomorphism $\phi : A \to A^{\ast}$ has the form
$$A \ni f(x) \mapsto \sum \phi_x f(x) x \in A^{\ast}$$
where $\phi_x \in k^{\times}$ are nonzero. So the transported comultiplication on $A$ takes the form
$$\Delta(e_x) = \phi_x^{-1} e_x \otimes e_x$$
where $e_x$ is the "standard basis vector" which is $1$ on $x$ and $0$ otherwise. This never preserves the unit if $|X| \ge 2$, for any choice of $\phi$, since the unit is $\sum_x e_x$ which is sent to $\sum \phi_x^{-1} e_x \otimes e_x$ rather than $(\sum_x e_x) \otimes (\sum_x e_x)$.
